# Azure AD B2C integration with external Idp and SSO to an application authenticated by the external Idp

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c

We are building a SPA in react. For users to sign in we are using Azure AD B2C as some of our users in the Azure Tenant. But we want to expand the user base and provide access to another set of users that another Idp manages. So We have decided to add the external Idp to our Azure B2C and now user see both options on the login screen.

There is a third party web application that the external Idp authenticates. So If we provide a link to that applications on our SPA, and if the user is signed into our SPA using the external Idp via Azure AD and when the user clicks on that link, we would like SSO to happen to that site and bypass the sign in feature.

Is this flow possible?

Comment: This flow is possible, however that 3rd party web application should have also registered with that external IdP. If the user's scopes and claims obtained using your SPA were all that is sufficient for that app as well, then it will be seamless and non-interactive.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I have used in the past is Scim2 which stands for System for Cross-domain Identity Management: http://www.simplecloud.info/

The Scim2 solution would allow for SSO across sites to bypass sign-on feature for Users in for AD Azure Tenant are signing on one time. The third party web application domain can be registered in your Azure Scim2 config.

How to setup Scim2 with Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/sync-scim

Comment: This may not suite my requirement as I am more looking to see if SSO to the 3rd party application is feasible or not

Comment: @MukundaPasumarthi You will have to check with the third party application provider if they have an endpoint where you can pass your token such as OpenID, this just depends on how the third party application is built